# @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babeljs

I have such a project structure:

```
/main-folder

  /apps
    /app — // I want to import "project-b" here
      /node_modules
      /public
      /src
        |app.js
        |app.css
      |.babelrc
      |package.json
      |package-lock.json
      |webpack.config.js

  /static
    /project-b — // Project that I want to export
      /node_modules
      /public
      /src
        /lib
          ...components
      |.babelrc
      |package.json
      |package-lock.json
```

Everything okay when I try to import components without class properties.
But if I import component with class properties:

[image]

I thought if I add `.babelrc` it'll work (I added `.babelrc` to the `app` and `project-b` folders and it still doesn't work)

**`.babelrc:`**

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-react","@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
  ]
}
```

**`app package.json:`**

```
{
  "name": "auth",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "start:dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "webpack:production": "webpack -p"
  },
  "author": "namename",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "entrl-ui-kit": "^1.0.3",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.5.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "webpack": "^4.26.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"
  }
}
```

**`project-b package.json:`**

```
 {
  "name": "project-b",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "namename",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build-examples": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build": "rimraf ./build && mkdirp ./build && babel -d ./build ./src"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.1.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.6",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.24.1",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.1",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.5.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you read through https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#monorepos?

Comment: @loganfsmyth, yes already, but I'm not sure what I need to do to solve this problem

Comment: One of the first sentences in that page is "The first step in any monorepo structure should be to create a babel.config.js file", which you don't appear to have in your example, nor the `babelrcRoots` described in that section. Are there ways that could be reworded to help?

Comment: @loganfsmyth, I reread what you sent me and solved my problem, ty very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All I need to do is add `babel.config.js` to the root folder:

Thanks to [loganfsmyth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785065/loganfsmyth)!

```
/main-folder
  |babel.config.js — //HERE!
  /apps
    /app — // I want to import "project-b" here
      /node_modules
      /public
      /src
        |app.js
        |app.css
      |.babelrc
      |package.json
      |package-lock.json
      |webpack.config.js

  /static
    /project-b — // Project that I want to export
      /node_modules
      /public
      /src
        /lib
          ...components
      |.babelrc
      |package.json
      |package-lock.json
```

**`babel.config.js:`**

```
module.exports = {
  babelrcRoots: [
    ".",
    "static/project-b/*"
  ]
};
```